How are different sensations of tiredness/exhaustion biologically different?
Last weekend I did some very vigorous work in the garden - fun, but I overdid it. I noticed I had several different types of tiredness/exhaustion, or at least different subjective sensations, and I'm interested how they are different physiologically.
(1) Saturday I left lunch too late and felt tired before eating, though just fine afterwards. Is this "only" blood sugar?
(2) On Sunday evening I felt pretty much literally too tired to think. I had a good night's sleep of my normal length and woke feeling good and alert as normal (of course tired).
(3) Monday and Tuesday I've continued feeling tired - not toxically tired, just the usual tiredness you'd expect after doing too much gardening, but without the foggy add-on that (2) seemed to have.
What is the body doing diferently in recovering from each of these three things? And can (2) and (3) indeed be different?

You're asking about something very subjective (fatigue), a condition that would require a fair number of questions to evaluate. This puts the question in the "medical advice" category. I'm voting to close for that reason.

I'm having trouble thinking of a way that someone would answer this question that does not become either a medical advice answer (as anongoodnurse is concerned with) or an overbroad introduction to fatigue. That sort of broad overview is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format, this is one of the reasons we have a requirement for "prior research" to narrow down a question asked. I might suggest you start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue - Wikipedia is often a good starting point for general information on a topic - and see if you have a specific, answerable question afterwards.

In particular, see the section "Classification".

@BryanKrause - Although I agree with you that Wikipedia is as good a starting place as almost any for a layperson, that section is sub-par (?), and unsupported by the cited reference. Maybe this is a better short answer that explains how complex fatigue is?

If this is not the right place to ask, OK. I'm asking about everyday experiences out of pure curiosity. There is clearly some difference between feeling tired but revived after eating; routinely tired after eg going to the gym; and gosh-I-overdid-it-in-the-garden (or HIIT, or marathon) that takes longer to bounce back from. These are the everyday experiences I'm asking about. The sharp difference between too tired to think but fine after a normal sleep, is doubtless uncommon but caught my attention. I guess mentioning it caused confusion, and it is maybe purely idiosyncratic.

@AndrewWhite - This isn't the wrong place to ask. It's just not answerable. Loads of people think of complex things in simple terms ("Clearly..." x is the same in the terms x and 4x.) Did you revive because you had a meal,  b/c you rested while eating, b/c you were looking forward to getting back, or all/none? There's no confusion. One school of thought is that fatigue unrelated to illness is just one thing but different in severity; then there's the complexity in the abstract, and lots of things in between. And fyi, dizziness and fatigue are extremely common complaints in medicine.
